# How to recognize rectangular or circular arrays in 2D point set

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to find suitable algorithms for recognition rectangular and circular arrays in 2D point set. For example, in the following images, the required points full filled black:

[image: rectangular]

[image: circular]

Comment: What do the unfilled circles represent?

Comment: Points that do not fit, because they do not organize the desired pattern

Comment: I don't follow. What are the data inputs to the program?

Comment: The set of two-dimensional points.

Comment: In coordinate form?

Comment: Sure, point represent as tuple (x, y)

Comment: Are the coordinates restricted in any way (e.g., are they integers?)

Comment: It's a float numbers

Comment: Please give a full input data sample with desired sample output (regard it as part of showing your work). That way, it can be discussed more concretely, and also, it allows for testing possible methods.

Comment: All the points in your input lie on circles, for any three noncollinear points form a circle. You might want to remember this as you formulate the problem more precisely. On the other hand, in floating-point coordinates, chances are good that NO triple of points lies on a circle, i.e., there's probably no floating-point "center" whose distances to any triple of input points are floating-point equal.  You might want to consider that as part of your problem formulation as well -- what's the "tolerance"?

Comment: Three points determine a circle, so what if you just try all subsets of size three. For a given set of three points, check to see if the corresponding circle meets with a bunch of other points.